# How to answer "The applicant’s overall rank is ? out of ? "

Tags: meaning-in-context, questions

I am filling a reference form and I met 2 questions that I am not sure how to answer :

> 1. The applicant’s overall rank is **__ out of *_*__**
> 2. Please describe the comparison group: **__**

If the applicant is my colleague and I am comparing him with other engineers who works in the same area, how should I answer this 2 questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first question is asking how large the group of engineers who work in the same area is and where the person fits into that group if you were to order them from best to worst.  So if there are 20 engineers in the group, and the person is the 3rd best engineer of those 20 you would say:

> The applicant's overall rank is 3 out of 20.

The second question is asking you to describe what constitutes the group of engineers who work in that same area.  For example, something like

> The comparison group is comprised of all software engineers who are actively working in embedded software.

This way it's clear with whom you're comparing him so that any bias based on group composition can be taken into account.